# Can i replace R13 rim with R14 rim

Tags: toyota

i want to replace R13 rims of my car with R14 rims. what are the effects on the fuel consumption and speed?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you tell us a little more about your car, the answers can be more specific. What year and model of Toyota do you have?

Comment: It will depend on the tires you choose as well. If you spec smaller sidewall tires, the effective radius of the wheel+tire will be the same, meaning you'd experience very little change in fuel consumption or speed.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of tyre fitted - if you fit a lower profile tyre to the 14" wheels so they that have the same overall diameter, it will have no effect.

Comment: But the 14" rim will probably be heavier thus reduced fuel consumption right?

Answer (score 1):

@Nick C And to go with your answer, here is a site (one among many available...) http://www.tyresave.co.uk/tyre-size-calculator/ that does the equivalance calculations to make sure your choices are sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Without much more information other than what you gave, we can still generally state that larger diameter wheels will reduce your fuel economy and your acceleration will be slower, though it is unlikely to be noticeable to you.

[This article](http://www.caranddriver.com/features/effects-of-upsized-wheels-and-tires-tested) by Car and Driver does a nice comparison for a VW Golf. The chart below summarizes the results of the test, which indicate that fuel economy and acceleration can suffer with larger wheels. The reason for this is that larger wheels tend to be more heavy (even with the lower profile of the tire). You are likely to gain more traction, resulting in better handling and braking ability.

[image: Effects of upsized wheels and tires tested]

The article doesn't mention it, but lower profile tires found on larger wheels tend to cost more.

Anecdotally, I recently went the other way and downsized my wheels from 19" to 17". I did this for many reasons, including the those outlined in the article, cost to replace tires, and ride comfort. You might notice that the ride is a bit more harsh with larger wheels.

---

Citations:
Car and Driver. (2010, April 09). Effects of Upsized Wheels and Tires Tested - Tech Dept. Retrieved May 04, 2017, from http://www.caranddriver.com/features/effects-of-upsized-wheels-and-tires-tested

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that overall tire diameter and width will remain the same.  I also assume that the rims are made of the same material.  Overall weight will decrease aiding acceleration, braking and gas mileage.  Since the rim is smaller, but the tire is the same diameter, you will have a larger sidewall.  A larger sidewall will give you a softer ride as it will absorb some of the impact from bumps.  The downside of a larger sidewall, is that it is less rigid and is more likely to deform during hard turns (you can end up driving on the sidewall).  As such, handling will not be as good with the smaller rims.

Another factor to consider is your brakes.  Your rim will need to be able to clear the brakes.  It is not uncommon to need at least a 14"-16" rim (depending on make/model) to clear the brakes.

Comment: The OP is going from 13 to 14", so the overall weight will increase (reduced rubber is overwhelmed by the increase in metal). Other than that, your statements are mostly correct for reducing wheel diameter.

Comment: Your right, don't know why I thought he was going the other way around.